# Taking a users input and saying it is part of a bigger category

Tags: python

Say for example that I have an Array of

```
samples = { 
       "Object": "chairs", "Stationary": "pencils", "Thing": "apples",
     }
```

And I have a code saying

```
print('Which stuff would you like?')
```

And the user inputs an answer that says pencils. How can I make it so that the program says it that you chose a stationary? 
And also could the user enter like chairs apples and the program would print you chose an object and 
a thing?
I have tried using for loops but I can't seem to get it right.
Any answers?

Comment: Are you using the dictionary for anything else? If you're always trying to do lookups using the value instead of the key, just invert the dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `'pencils'` to look up `'Stationary'` rather than vice-versa, why not swap the keys and values so you can use it as a dictionary is intended to be used?

```py
samples = { 
    "chairs": "Object",
    "pencils": "Stationary",
    "apples": "Thing",
}

thing = input("Which stuff would you like? ")
if thing in samples:
    print("The category is", samples[thing])
else:
    print("I don't know what it is")
```

Comment: I don't want it vice-versa sorry any way else?

Comment: I want it so that the user says he wants stationery and so that the program will say pencils.

Comment: That's the opposite of what you wrote in the question, but in that case all you have to do is not swap the keys and values in the dictionary, and this code will have the desired behaviour.

Comment: @Fortniteisgood Why don’t you want to invert it? What are you actually asking for? This is seriously unclear.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved in one line.

```
user_input = input()
print(list(samples.keys())[list(samples.values()).index(user_input)])
```

Some information about how Dictionaries work on Python can be found here https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp